# Solving the functional equations $f(g(x)) = \sin x$ and $g(f(x)) = \cos x$

Tags: functional-equations

> Solving the functional equations $f(g(x)) = \sin x$ and $g(f(x)) = \cos x$ .

I've managed to reduce an expression for $f(x)$ as:

$f(\cos x) = \sin(f(x))$

But I have no idea how to proceed. I would appreciate some help !

Comment: Welcome to MSE. A question should be written in such a way that it can be understood even by someone who did not read its title.

Comment: Where is this problem from? Do you have any reason to believe that this system of equations have a solution or that the solution have a closed form in terms of known functions? It's often not then case for this kind of functional equations...

Comment: [This post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3352539) seems to show there are no such continuous functions

Answer (score 2):

(Too long for a comment.)

If we assume that $g(x)$ is nice enough to have a Taylor series, then there is no solution.

Going in the other direction (i.e. replacing $x$ with $g(x)$ in the cosine equation and reduce using the sine equation), we get

$$ g(\sin x) = \cos g(x). $$

Putting $g(x) = a_0 + a_1 x + a_2 x^2 + \text{etc.}$, [we get](https://tio.run/##hY4xC8IwEIX3/IpHJ4UOjmKNCMVRENItRDlrWgMmlTZCQPrbY6qTIDgcHPfu@3iW/FVb8qamGN2eAjiWBWtlOCmsOMTDyllGGdYbVJ3wvXGtdGqOcHQ5nmkWOSZuVAU7pNRLBlR0vulpAXbhTu6CLYTujR7KTjeNqY1Oj60UxsmgVBKFj2hUbwjg/B9ddkMy/KK/e6WTYqlcjC8)

\begin{align}
  a_0 &= \cos a_0 &&(1) \\
  a_1 &= -a_1 S &&(x) \\
  a_2 &= -\frac{{a_1}^2 C}{2} - a_2 S &&(x^2) \\
  -\frac{a_1}{6} + a_3 &= \frac{{a_1}^3 S}{6} - a_1 a_2 C - a_3 S &&(x^3) \\
  -\frac{a_2}{3} + a_4 &= \text{(terms with $a_1$, $a_2$, $a_3$)} - a_4 S &&(x^4) \\
  \frac{a_1}{120} - \frac{a_3}{2} + a_5 &= \text{(terms with $a_1$, $a_2$, $a_3$, $a_4$)} - a_5 S &&(x^5) \\
  \frac{2 a_2}{45} - \frac{2 a_4}{3} + a_6 &= \text{(terms with $a_1$, $a_2$, $a_3$, $a_4$, $a_5$)} - a_6 S &&(x^6) \\
  &\text{etc.}
\end{align}

where $C = \cos a_0$ and $S = \sin a_0$.

We see that $a_0$ is the [Dottie number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dottie_number), the unique real fixed point of the cosine function (so that $C = 0.739...$ and $S = 0.673...$). All subsequent coefficients vanish, as the equation for the coefficient of $x^n$ (for $n \ge 1$) reduces to

$$a_n = -a_n S.$$

Thus $g(x) = a_0$, and the sine equation becomes $f(a_0) = \sin x$, a contradiction.

---

This of course doesn't rule out the possibility of solutions where $g(x)$ doesn't have a Taylor series.